# File.WriteAllText issue

Tags: c#, file, save, writealltext

I am trying to save a number of different forms to a text file, currently I have:

- Temperature
- Wind
- Rain
- Cloud

The issue that I'm having is that it only saves the "Cloud" data.  Is there a way I can save all the information on submission and have them separated by a comma, dash, or just a space?

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        File.WriteAllText("C:\\WeatherSpotter.txt", tempC.Text);
        File.WriteAllText("C:\\WeatherSpotter.txt", tempF.Text);
        File.WriteAllText("C:\\WeatherSpotter.txt", windMPH.Text);
        File.WriteAllText("C:\\WeatherSpotter.txt", windKM_Textbox.Text);
        File.WriteAllText("C:\\WeatherSpotter.txt", Cloud_ComboBox.Text);


    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`File.WriteAllText` replaces the contents of the file.

You want `File.AppendText()`, which does [exactly what it says on the tin](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ExactlyWhatItSaysOnTheTin).
Note that you may or may not want the first call to still be `WriteAllText()`.

Or, better yet, concatenate all of that into a single string and call `WriteAllText()` only once.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you invoke `File.WriteAllText` you overwrite the existing file. You instead should be using an append function such as `File.AppendText()` or opening the file, writing each of the lines, then closing it. You could also use `StringBuilder` or something to build the entire file contents.

There are so many options, just be sure to check how the method you choose handles the file (what mode/permissions it uses).